# Quicksand plugin and lazy loader

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, quicksand

i'm using Quicksand plugin (http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) for displaying images.
Because i plan to have a lot of them, i wanted to add lazy loader plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to increase performance a little.

I have a strange problem when i combine those two together:

1. If i put Quicksand in front of lazyloader, quicksand will work, but lazy loader wont.
2. And vice versa, if i put lazy load in front of quicksand, lazy works and sand doesnt.
3. If i put them in seperate files (eg sand.js and lazy.js) and order them so that sand.js is first and lazy.js second, both after jqeury.js, they will work together to some point. Quicksand filter works, but it displays empty images.

I've read all the answers on stackoverflow (i think), googled for 2 hours and as i see all comes down to callback. I read the quicksand documentation but got more confused.

I would appriciate some help, as i dont know how to use callbacks - i'm jquery noob.

I've setup a jsfiddle, if it's any help: http://jsfiddle.net/zUAVA/

(with this setup lazy works, but quicksand doesnt)

Thanks for any help.

Edit: If i use option 3. (above), the images show up when the page loads, but soon as i start to use filter, they will all go blank.

Answer (score 1):

Adding lazyload and $(window).trigger("scroll") to the quicksand callback seems to work for me.